# Saving Method for a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

this is my code in my .m file

```
@interface HomeWorkViewController ()



@end

@implementation HomeWorkViewController
@synthesize adView;
@synthesize myTableView, numbers;


-(void) viewDidLoad
{

   adView.delegate=self;
    [super viewDidLoad];

      self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    // check here if key exists in the defaults or not, if yes the retrieve results in array
    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"numberArray"] != nil) {
        self.numbers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"numberArray"]];

    }

    //Register for the notification when user go to background or minimize the app, just save the array objects in the defaults

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]   addObserver:self
                                               selector:@selector(appWillGoToBackground:)
                                                   name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
                                                 object:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];

    //Add the Add button
    UIBarButtonItem * addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target: self action: @selector(insertNewObject)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
}

-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.myTableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];

}
-(void)appWillGoToBackground:(NSNotification *)note {
    NSLog(@"terminate");

    NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:self.numbers forKey:@"numberArray"];
    [defaults synchronize];

}

-(void)insertNewObject{
    //Display a UIAlertView
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Enter HomeWork" message: @"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];


    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [alert show];


}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    //Only perform the following actions if the user hits the ok button
    if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        NSString * tmpTextField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;



        if(!self. numbers){

            self.numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        }



        [self.numbers insertObject:tmpTextField atIndex:0];



        NSIndexPath * indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

        [self.myTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];




    }

}

    -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        return 1;
    }

    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
        return self.numbers.count;
    }

    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [ tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        if(cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                          reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier];
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = [self.numbers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;
    }

    -(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        return YES;

    }

    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
        {
            //remove our NSMutableArray
            [self.numbers removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            //remove from our tableView
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }


    }


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath
toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{


}
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    adView.hidden=FALSE;
    NSLog(@"Has ad, showing");

}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    adView.hidden=TRUE;
    NSLog(@"Has no ads, hiding");

}

-(void)dealloc
{



    [adView release];
    [super dealloc];


}


@end
```

I have a saving method there but I want to save everything that I changed in the table by clicking a button.   How do i do that?
I want to put a toolbar with a button that says back to go to the home screen, and link this button to save everything that was done to the table like delete, switch order and add.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there :)

You are using the numbers array as the data model for the table.
Make sure that this array is always updated when the table is manipulated. (For example, you need to reorder the numbers array in `moveRowAtIndexPath`. Currently, you do nothing in that method)

To save the model using a button, just create a UIButton in the Interface Builder and connect it to the following action:

```
- (IBAction)saveButtonWasPressed:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:self.numbers forKey:@"numberArray"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Maybe you also want to pop the tableviewcontroller from the navigationcontroller stack if you also want to leave the controller.

Comment: You will never learn if your just handed the code. Here is an excellent tutorial for enabling editing of a table. http://behindtechlines.com/2012/06/enabling-configuring-uitableview-edit-mode/

Comment: How do I link it if i am using storyboarding

Comment: To link, first add the method in both the .h and .m files for your controller. Open your storyboard in xcode, add the UIButton, enter the "split view mode" in xcode where you can see both your storyboard and the .h file for your controller. Then control-drag from your button to the method in the .h file.

Comment: Even easier, add the method body afterwards: Control-drag to an empty line in the .h file. You will be prompted to enter the action name, type saveButtonWasPressed and choose action. Your method will then be created in the .h and .m file. Then paste the code that actually does something inside the method in the .m file.